# Delete Tr in Iterated *ngFor Using Template Driven in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, tr, angular-template, angular-forms

How can I delete this row using template driven form? I'm confused since the arrays is iterated in `*ngFor`? how can I do this? Here's what I've done below.

> HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let innerItem of project.material_projects | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction} |  let i = index">
    <td>{{innerItem.material.name}}</td>
    <td>{{innerItem.balance}}</td>
    <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="onDelete(i)"> Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

> TS

```
onDelete(index: number) {
      this.projects.material_projects.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your logical part :

```
| orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction} |
```

This is reordering your `project.material_projects` array, and you are using the index of the reordered array, so you need to perform the same operation before this line :

```
this.projects.material_projects.splice(index, 1)
```

And it's done.

---

OR

You can pass the `id` if its unique liek , `onDelete(innerItem.id)`

Then

```
onDelete(id: number) {
    let index = // logic to find index of that id ;
    this.projects.material_projects.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the HTML part. I'm confused  of what youre saying. Thanks

Comment: @Joseph, please create a plnkr for this, I will show you there. you can follow the second way it's very clear.

Comment: @Joseph, Will you please create plnkr for this ?

Comment: Because this.projects has several projects in it so it cant be

Comment: @Joseph, Please read the answer carefully, its very simple and clear.

Comment: I mean this tr is under the *ngFor=let project of projects. I have several projects in it and each let project of projects has this tr

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
<tr *ngFor="let i = index; let innerItem of project.material_projects | orderBy: { property: column, direction: direction }">
    <td>{{innerItem.material.name}}</td>
    <td>{{innerItem.balance}}</td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="onDelete(i)"> Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and ts onDelete method like below :

```
onDelete(index) {
    this.project.material_projects.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this tr is under *ngFor=let project of projects. So that is why  the error splice is undefined shows up

Comment: @Joseph try tr tag like this :- <tr *ngFor="let i = index; let innerItem of project.material_projects | orderBy: column: direction;">

Comment: Do not touch the orderBy because i have the fa-ort pipe that either desc or ascn it depends on what arrow im pressing

Comment: The declared array name is `project.material_projects` or `projects.material_projects` check this first . you are displayed template project.material_projects and typescript onDelete method declare `this.projects.material_projects.splice(...)`

Comment: if `project.material_projects` is an array the splice method will work otherwise check the onDelete method and tr Tag. just print the console of index inside the onDelete method and use tr tag like this : `<tr *ngFor="let i = index; let innerItem of project.material_projects | orderByNew: { property: column, direction: direction }"></tr>` it's working for me

Comment: This is working this.projects[0].material_projects.splice(...). However it only delete the first projects row. If i dont put the [0], then the splice is undefined error showS